# Облость видимости объекта в express and mysql passport-local

Tags: node.js, express

Сохраняю данные из mysql в объект на nodejs(express) если обращаться: `app.get("/cabin",auth, (request, response) => { response.render('cabin',{ login:${person.login} }`
Логин есть, но как только я пытаюсь выйти за пределы "app.get or app.post" то весь объект остается undefined. Пытался искать область видимости, использовал global.login. Но проблема остается. Объект var person={}; объявлен пустым до обращения в sql потом открывается SQL через for остается выборка с login and name,password. Надо сохранить эту часть в буфер для id не просто объект с sql вообще все что было записано пропадает, поэтому открываю sql в пределах app.use(passport... (authUser)-получает логин пароль для входа на сайт, ок! Но потом все данные можно использовать только в области видимости app.get и если попытаться создать папку `app.use(multer({dest:"public/uploads/"+${uploadFile}}).single("filedata"));`
то директория называется undefined
Как сделать объект видимым во всем скрипте?
Искал какой-нибудь буфер для данных в nodejs Может есть какой нибудь способ? авторизация проходит через for по всй mysql и после авторизации желательно бы сохрянять карточку чтобы данные остались в глобальной области видимости. global.login - тоже возвращает undefined. Или что делать то?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На изображении директория создается с нормальным именем все ок, но за пределами function auntUser объекта person уже не существует.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
 authUser = async (user, password, done) => {
    console.log(`User is ${user}`);
    console.log(`Password is ${password}`);
    function usPas(){
    console.log("^_^"+`${user}`);
    console.log("***"+`${password}`);
    }
    await usPas();
    //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    const pathUser='user';


    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: `${mysqlhost}`,
      user: `${mysqluser}`,
      password: `${mysqlpassword}`,
      database: `${mysqldatabase}`
    });
      connection.connect(err=>{
        if(err){
          return err;
          console.log('err');
        }else{
          console.log('database--- oK');
        }
      });
      const sql = `SELECT * FROM barbarians`;
      connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        // console.log(results.length);
        // console.log(results);

  for(let y=0;y<results.length;y++){
    // console.log(results[y].login+"____"+results[y].password+"___"+'////'+`${user}`+"---"+`${password}`+'_FIRST-PUSH');
    if(results[y].login==`${user}`&&results[y].password==`${password}`){

      
    person={
        id:results[y].id,
        login:results[y].login,
        pwd:results[y].password,
        email:results[y].email,
        name:results[y].Name,
        lastname:results[y].Lastname,
        age:results[y].age,
        gender:results[y].gender,
        blod_type:results[y].blod_type,
        profession:results[y].profession,
        having_children:results[y].having_children,
        marital_status:results[y].marital_status,
        hobby:results[y].hobby,
        education:results[y].education,
        visit_date:results[y].visit_date,

      }
      fs.writeFile('public/uploads/globalName.json',`${person.login}`,(err)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log('oK');
      });
      // global.login=`${person.login}`;
      function personLoginAndProfile(){
        // const globalName=fs.writeFileSync('public/uploads/globalName.json',`${person.login}`);
        global.login=`${person.login}`;
        const folderName='public/uploads/'+`${person.login}`;
        try{
          if(!fs.existsSync(folderName)){
            fs.mkdirSync(folderName);
          }
        }catch(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
      personLoginAndProfile();//<-this function throws an error file is created but the page redirects to an error: The connection was reset
      // console.log(person.login+'___<- if login');

    }else{
      // console.log('FALSE');
    }
    // var logins=results[y].login;
    // var password=results[y].password;

  }

        });//connection
        // console.log(`${logina}`+"<---------------------------");

      //******************************************************************************


      //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

        connection.end(err=>{
          if(err){
            return err;
            console.log('err');
          }else{
            console.log('database ADD --- closed');
          }
        });//connection closed

      //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxx
      setTimeout(()=>{


        // console.log(`${person.login}`+"////"+ `${person.pwd}`+'<---------What?');
        // console.log(`${user}`+"////"+ `${password}`+'<---------What two?')
        //a miracle happens here
        // function vsePush(){
          if (user == `${person.login}` && password == `${person.pwd}`) {
            return done(null, { id: `${person.id}`, name: `${person.login}` ,visit_date:`${person.visit_date}`});
          }else{
            // message='incorrect login or password';
          }
          return done(null, false);

      },700);
      // }

}//authUser
console.log(typeof(authUser));
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(authUser));
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user)
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user)
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/home",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
}));


app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
  
  
    response.render('login',{
      title:"authorization",
      text: "TEXT",
      description: "ddfs",
      info: `${message}`
    });
});

auth = (request, response, next) => {
    if (request.user != undefined) next();
    response.redirect("/login");// ОШИБКА
    // message='not login or password';
}

app.post("/exit", (request, response) => {
  request.logOut();
  response.redirect('/');
});
app.get("/home",auth, (request, response) => {

  response.render('home',{

    title:"authorization Success!",
    text: "777 laborum.",
    description: "ddfs",
    name: `${person.name}`

  });
});
app.get("/script",auth, (request, response) => {
  console.log('lol');
  response.render('script',{

    title:"authorization Success!",
    text: "Excess!",
    description: "ddfs",
    name: `${person.name}`

  });
});


app.get("/cabin",auth, (request, response) => {
  response.render('cabin',{
    title:"is this are cabins!",
    text: "This is actually real. Spacecraft control room!",
    description: "cabin user",
    name: `${person.name}`,
    login:`${person.login}`,
    email:`${person.email}`,
    name:`${person.name}`,
    lastname:`${person.lastname}`,
    gender:`${person.gender}`,
    age:`${person.age}`,
    blod_type:`${person.blod_type}`,
    profession:`${person.profession}`,
    having_children:`${person.having_children}`,
    marital_status:`${person.marital_status}`,
    hobby:`${person.hobby}`,
    education:`${person.education}`,
  });
  // console.log(ruquerst.url);
});
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
global.uploadFile=`${person.login}`;//why is the variable undefined???

function sendRes(url, contentType, res){
  let file=path.join(__dirname+'/public/upload/321/')
  fs.readFile(file,(err,content)=>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': contentType});
      res.write('file not found');
      res.end();
    }
  })
};
// console.log(`${person.name}`+'<---------------------------------***')
// function getRandomInt(max) {
  //
  //   console.log(person.login+'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000');
  //   return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  // }
  // // global.login=getRandomInt(999);
  // // global.login=`${person.getFullName}`;
  // console.log(`${global.login}`+"<---------------------------");
  // console.log(`${global.login}`+"---<- Two LOGIN");
  app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

  // var uploadFile=`${person.name}`;
  global.uploadFile=`${person.login}`;
  app.use(multer({dest:"public/uploads/"+`${uploadFile}`}).single("filedata"));
  //in this place the code does not work the file name is undefined

  app.post("/public/upload", function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.url);
    let filedata = req.file;
    console.log(filedata);
    if(!filedata)
    res.send("err");
    else
    res.send("file uploaded");
  });
  //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
app.post('/cabinUpdateEmail',auth,(request,response)=>{
  response.render('cabin',{
    title:"is this are cabins!",
    text: "This is actually real. Spacecraft control room!",
    description: "cabin user",

    email:`${person.email}`,

  });
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: `${mysqlhost}`,
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)